# Trigger For select and insert into two banks

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, triggers, insert

We have two servers, one for CRM and one for accounting.
Now I want to insert the invoice record into the CRM bank.
I know how to select and insert in one table with trigger.
The question is how to insert the selected record into another table on another server.

Comment: Replication/SSIS/linked server and trigger/... Please specify RDBMS you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linked server is something that you can use to treat databases on another server like a database on your server.
You can make it easily in Sql Management Studio (for SQL Server).

In a trigger on insert for a table in one database, you can insert in another database table.

Comment: Are you aware that it will slow inserts? Distributed transaction in triggers could be painful (depending on workload).